# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am getting this error'PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments' in following Procedure:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure TEST1(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)

as

 sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select UTL_ID,';

begin
    for x in (select distinct tyt_id from GTEMP_TPOAR order by 1)
    loop
        sql_query := sql_query ||
          'sum(case when tyt_id = '||x|| ' then  cnt end)'|| x ||',';

            dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
    end loop;

    sql_query := RTRIM(sql_query, ',');
    sql_query := sql_query || ' from GTEMP_TPOAR';

    open p_cursor for sql_query;
end;
```

I am using oracle 10g

Comment: How did you run this procedure?

Comment: Where do you want your procedure to be executed? From sqlplus or from frontend application? Did you compile procedure without any errors?

Comment: Issue is fixed,It was compilation error in sql developer

Comment: Good to know it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error.I have to use x.tytid